# AWS API Gateway Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've wasted all day on this one. For some reason this works with method GET but when I try it with method PUT I get

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I've enabled CORS via API Gateway and Deployed the API. My response contains

```
    return {
        'statusCode': statusCode,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(body),
        'isBase64Encoded': False
    }
```

My jquery looks like this

```
var options = {};
options['url'] = URL;
options['method'] = METHOD;
options['contentType']  = 'application/json';
options['headers'] = { 'x-api-key': KEY }

$.ajax(options).done(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up nothing was wrong with the API Gateway my lambda wasn't returning what I thought it was.

Comment: What do you mean can you explain the issue